# Difference between requests module and aiohttp/httpx module from Asyncio perspective

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-requests, python-asyncio

My question is what *exactly* makes `requests` module incompatible and `httpx`, `aiohttp` modules compatible with Asyncio framework behind the scene?

I'm familiar with Asynchronous concepts and how it works but apparently I'm missing something obvious(!) that leads me to ask this question.

From my understanding, The bottom line is (Please correct me if I'm wrong):
In event loop, when a socket is asked for data, if it has data we get it immediately, if the buffer is empty(an exception is raised and with a try-except mechanism), it's going to be registered to the [`select`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#module-select) function and a Future object for that is scheduled to the event loop.

Another difference I guess is the socket has to be [non-blocking](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#notes-on-socket-timeouts).

> In non-blocking mode, operations fail (with an error that is
> unfortunately system-dependent) if they cannot be completed
> immediately: functions from the `select` can be used to know when and
> whether a socket is available for reading or writing.

So it's all about the interaction between `select` function and the operating system and their heart is the same. Why AsyncIO can't play well with `requests` module? Or another naive question is, how hard is it to make `requests` module compatible with AsyncIO framework? Is it just because there are lots of intermediate blocking functions that needs to be replaced with non-blocking version?

Comment: asyncio requires use of `async` and `await`. requests doesn’t use them. You’d need to replace all of the blocking functions in requests with asynchronous ones in order for it to be compatible.

Comment: @dirn What I was trying to say is, if in the heart of both frameworks they do the same thing, AsyncIO can manage to handle that inner-most IO blocking call which is reading from a socket(By creating a Future object for that)! That would give us a huge performance increase(of course not as same as those fully async written frameworks but to a good extent). I'm aware that requests module doesn't use new async-await syntax but that blocking function call can be managed just like how it's managed in `aiohttp` and `httpx`.

Comment: `requests` doesn't yield execution privilege back to the Python event loop until the request is done. Whether this is because it's using the "wrong" `select` internally or whatever is somewhat irrelevant; you could investigate this by digging into the code. The simple fact is that none of the `requests` code has been written with the idea of yielding back to an event loop. That's why. How much work it would be to rewrite every part of `requests` to work nicely with event loops is really way too broad, that requires in-depth analysis of the entire code base.